# cannot find pysat=0.1.3 dependency

Tags: deep-learning, graph-coloring, gnn

I am getting error as

```py
from pysat.solvers import Glucose3
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysat.solvers'*
```

when I am trying newer version of `pysat`.
I cannot find the required older version that is `pysat=0.1.3`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, try to use `pip install -U python-sat` or `pip3 install -U python-sat` command to install the toolkit.
Reference: "https://pysathq.github.io/installation/".